# Hide div overlay on page load or back navigation not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div overlay that shows a loading gif. When the page is loaded, the div overlay is supposed to disappear.

```
<div id="posts">
  <div id="loading" style="display: none;">
    <img id="loading-image" src="/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">
  </div>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

To hide the div overlay, I was using:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  // hide loading div
  $('#loading').hide();
})
```

In **Chrome**, if I navigate to some link, then navigate "back", the loading div overlay doesn't hide. It only hides when I reload the page.

If I add `unload` or `beforeunload` to the jQuery event list, I get the behavior I want, but `unload` is deprecated and `beforeunload` will likely cause cache problems and performance issues.

The way I understand it, a `load` event isn't triggered when a user hits "back".

But I want the div overlay to disappear when page is loaded OR when user hits back to page.

How can I achieve this without taking a performance hit?

I've tried `DomContentLoaded` with regular js.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let loading = document.querySelector('#loading');
  loading.style.display = 'none';
  console.log('Loaded');
})
```

"Loaded" prints in the console, but the overlay has an empty style tag, like so:

```
<div id="loading" style>...</div>
```

`window.addEventListener('pageshow', function() {...}` seems to work but I'm not sure if it will cause a performance hit or if it's the best solution. Never used it before.

Is this a Chrome thing? Is there a Chrome setting I should look at? I test in MS Edge and Firefox and `$('#loading').hide();` works fine on load and back navigation.

**Chrome version**: Version 101.0.4951.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Even this logs to the console but doesn't hide the div in Chrome!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#loading').hide();
  console.log('Should be hidden?')
})
```

**Edit**

By default, CSS displays this overlay with `display: block;`. When the page loads, I set this CSS property to `none` to hide it.

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Please explain how the loading overlay is shown, which seems an important part of this question.  As a test, you might also open Chrome dev tools (F12) and on the network tab disable cache.  And with the tools panel open, try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Yogi You are right. I added an edit to my question. The overlay shows when the page loads. I use Javascript to hide it when everything is finished loading. I've disabled cache on network tab many times during trouble-shooting. It has no effect either way.